# How to make sticky elements in meteor

Tags: jquery, css, meteor, sticky

I would like to make a sticky element using meteor, where the element would scroll until it reaches the top of the page, in which case it would remain there.

Specifically, I would like a "two stage" navbar with the first part disappearing as one scrolls down leaving the lower part fixed on the top of the page.

I couldn't find anywhere how to handle this on meteor and  it appears [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24111765/scroll-event-for-meteor) that you cannot use window scroll events.

I have tried a combination of the approaches [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31183455/window-scroll-is-running-even-if-the-template-is-destroyed-in-meteor) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1216114/how-can-i-make-a-div-stick-to-the-top-of-the-screen-once-its-been-scrolled-to) (cf edit below) but couldn't make it work!

Could anyone please help me out or give any pointers on how to go about implementing this in meteor?

**EDIT**

Here is an example of the sort of things I was trying if that helps, but it is so broken the page won't even load!

*layout.html:*

```
<template name="layout">

  <div class="banner">
      <!-- A full strip of text/logos ect -->
  </div>

 <div class ="headerAnchor"></div>

 <header id="header" class="relative">
     <!-- The navbar with all the links-->
 </header>

</template>
```

*layout.js:*

```
Template.layout.onRendered(function(){
  this.$anchor =$("#headerAnchor");
  this.$header = $("#header");

  this.navBarScrollHandler=function(){
   let st=$(window).scrollTop();
   let ot=this.$anchor.offset().top;
   if(st>ot){
     this.$header.removeClass(relative).addClass(fixed-on-top);
   }else if(st<=ot){
     this.$header.removeClass(fixed-on-top).addClass(relative);
   }
  }.bind(this);

  $window.on("scroll",this.navBarScrollHandler);

 });

Template.layout.onDestroyed(function(){
   $(window).off("scroll", this.scrollHandler);
});
```

*main.css:*

```
.fixed-on-top{
  position:fixed;
  top:0px;
 }  

.relative{
  position:relative !important;
 }
```

PS: What I would like is for `header` to have a relative position until `banner` is out of the page, then for `header` to be fixed on top unless you scroll all the way up again in which case `banner` would reappear.

Comment: Show us what you have tried yet ?

Comment: Yes! I have added an example of the sort of things I was trying however I feel I am quite far from the solution which is why I hesitated having this there!